# Find parent of node in binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, parent

I have trouble with a task to find a parent of a specific node in a binary search tree. The solution should be straightforward, but I don't know why my code is not working...I tried different approaches and also searched on the web for any solutions but found nothing. I appreciate any help!!

```
typedef struct Treenode{
    int key;
    struct Treenode* lChild;
    struct Treenode* rChild;
}node;

node * getParent(node *root, int key){
    if (root == NULL) return NULL;
    else if (root->rChild->key == key || root->lChild->key == key) return root;
    else if (root->key > key) getParent(root->lChild, key);
    else getParent(root->rChild, key);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return the result of recursive invocation! Another thing you may want to do is to remove all `else`s that follow a `return`, because they have no effect.

Comment: also need guard like as `root->rChild && root->rChild->key == key || root->lChild && root->lChild->key == key`

Answer (score 4):

```
else if (root->key > key) getParent(root->lChild, key);
else getParent(root->rChild, key);
```

In these two cases, you should just `return getParent(...);`. Otherwise the result of recursive call is simply dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return value of function to a node p, let say as it is of type node*, otherwise the code would not be able to return anything.

Comment: Please add some code for your solution for better help.